# I am getting "Conversion from String to type Double is invalid" in a database insert query

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing an application for a store where the bill number, Customer's Name and a few such values are inserted from the Text box and other vales such as Product, Price, etc. are from the DataGridView, but there is an error when I try to save the data from the DataGridView.

I've tried many solutions provided on internet and youtube, but none worked.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim product As String
    Dim price, discount, quantity As Integer
    For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount
        product = DataGridView2.Rows(x).Cells(0).ToString
        price = DataGridView2.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString
        discount = DataGridView2.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value.ToString
        quantity = DataGridView2.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value.ToString

        query = "insert into Bill values(" + TextBox1.Text + ",'" + product + "'," + price + ",'" + TextBox3.Text + "'," + discount + "," + quantity + "," + TextBox11.Text + ")"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(query, Log)

        Try
            Log.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("DATA SAVED", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Log.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next

End Sub
```

I just want the values from the text box and data grid view to be saved in the database, but there is an error stating

> Conversion from String to type Double is invalid.

The Error is on the insert query.

I've tried many solutions provided on the internet, but none worked for me.

Comment: Can you provide us the datatype of each column in the Bill table ?

Comment: Please look at my answer below, your error is due to the plus sign in your query. The error is tring to ADD a string and expecting a result of a double which is impossible. Just change the `+` to `&` in your query string.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `product = DataGridView2.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString()`, i.e. with the `.Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIRSTLY please try use stored procedures they are MUCH MUCH more easy to read and write especially when stuff like this happens
So you would have a stored procedure in your database editing software such as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEND_BILL_DETAILS](@PRODUCT VARCHAR(MAX),@PRICE INT,DISCOUNT VALUETYPE, @QUANTITY INT)
AS
BEGIN

    insert into Bill values(@PRODUCT,@PRICE,@DISCOUNT,@QUANTITY)

END
```

Then in your VB you would have something similar like this to aply the variables and execute the SP.

```
private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim product As String
        Dim price, discount, quantity As Integer
        For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount
            product = DataGridView2.Rows(x).Cells(0).ToString
            price = DataGridView2.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            discount = DataGridView2.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value.ToString
            quantity = DataGridView2.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value.ToString

            dim cmd as new sqlcommand("SEND_BILL_DETAILS",con)
            cmd.commandtype = commandtype.storeprocedure
            cmd.parameter.add(@product,sqldbtype.varchar).value = product.tostring()
            -----do one for each variable in stored procedure.
            Try
                log.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("DATA SAVED", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                log.Close()
                cmd.parameters.clear()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next

    End Sub
```

Now for you could I am assuming its a case of replacing all your `+` in your sql query to `&` as the program is attempting to literally add the words together so therefore would be something like this:

**FOR YOUR WAY OF DOING IT**

```
query = "insert into Bill values( '" & TextBox1.Text &",'" & product & "'," & price & ",'" & TextBox3.Text & "'," & discount & "," & quantity & "," & TextBox11.Text & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution you provided, I appreciate you participation, I hope that replacing will work. Thanks once again

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, Thank you so much, it did work :)

Comment: @Drago Great to hear! Please accept my answer by clicking the tick symbol beside it. Good luck

Comment: This answer has problems.  For one, you are trying to assign strings to integer variables (`price`, `discount` and `quantity`).  Turn `Option Strict On` and it will make it easier to track down such bugs.